# Customer Group not editing in orders admin after save opencart

Tags: edit, orders, opencart2.x

in admin orders page where I want to change the order to which customer group it will allow other edits except the customer group page.  Anyone know how to fix this issue? opencart 2.0.1.1

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess its more or less the same as from Oscommerce where I also just found this bug.
There is a mistake in calling cID for delete button

**admin/customers_groups.php**

At the end of document, around line 800:

find:

```
$contents[] = array(
 'align' => 'center',
 'text' => tep_draw_button(
    IMAGE_EDIT,
    'document',
    tep_href_link(
       FILENAME_CUSTOMERS_GROUPS,
       tep_get_all_get_params(
          array('cID', 'action')
       ) . 'cID=' . **$cInfo->categories_group_id** . '&action=edit')
    ) . tep_draw_button(
          IMAGE_DELETE,
          'trash',
          tep_href_link(
             FILENAME_CUSTOMERS_GROUPS,
             tep_get_all_get_params(
                array('cID', 'action')
             ) . 'cID=' . **$cInfo->categories_group_id** . '&action=confirm'
          )
    )
);
```

Change:
**$cInfo->categories_group_id**

To:
**$cInfo->customers_group_id**

Looks like it was a typo in some update ..

Hope it helps.